# google cloud dataflow hangs and can't cancel job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Trying to test out google dataflow by running an example from the google cloud datascience book. The code can be found here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/data-science-on-gcp/blob/master/04_streaming/simulate/df06.py

Below is the submission output:

```
(venv) ➜  simulate git:(master) ✗ python df06.py -p gcp-datascience-book -b ds-book-admix -d airports
Correcting timestamps and writing to BigQuery dataset airports
/Users/Yoda/Documents/google_datascience/data-science-on-gcp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py:166: DeprecationWarning: object() takes no parameters
  super(GcsIO, cls).__new__(cls, storage_client))
running sdist
running egg_info
writing requirements to flightsdf.egg-info/requires.txt
writing flightsdf.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to flightsdf.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to flightsdf.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'flightsdf.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'flightsdf.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst, README.txt, README.md

running check
warning: check: missing required meta-data: url

warning: check: missing meta-data: either (author and author_email) or (maintainer and maintainer_email) must be supplied

creating flightsdf-0.0.1
creating flightsdf-0.0.1/flightsdf.egg-info
copying files to flightsdf-0.0.1...
copying df06.py -> flightsdf-0.0.1
copying setup.py -> flightsdf-0.0.1
copying flightsdf.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> flightsdf-0.0.1/flightsdf.egg-info
copying flightsdf.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> flightsdf-0.0.1/flightsdf.egg-info
copying flightsdf.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> flightsdf-0.0.1/flightsdf.egg-info
copying flightsdf.egg-info/requires.txt -> flightsdf-0.0.1/flightsdf.egg-info
copying flightsdf.egg-info/top_level.txt -> flightsdf-0.0.1/flightsdf.egg-info
Writing flightsdf-0.0.1/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'flightsdf-0.0.1' (and everything under it)
Collecting google-cloud-dataflow==2.4.0
Successfully downloaded google-cloud-dataflow
```

Unfortunately, the process has been hanging for hours. In the dataflow console it tells me that the job doesn't exist and the status says "not started".

My attempts to cancel the job have been futile:

```
(venv) ➜  simulate git:(master) ✗ gcloud beta dataflow jobs --project=gcp-datascience-book cancel 2018-06-08_12_31_28-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Failed to cancel job [2018-06-08_12_31_28-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]: (82e778296697bc7f): Workflow modification failed. Causes: (8ad1157dde9a5d43): Operation cancel not allowed for job 2018-06-08_12_31_28-5106434125712000794. Job is not yet ready for canceling. Please retry in a few minutes.
```

Not sure what the problem is since I'm using code from a cloned repo that is supposed to accompany the book.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

one idea: what about killing your .py with bash of your gcloud console ?
Ctrl + C and / or pkill -f ./df06.py if it's in background